# Ogr2Ogr: Failed to create GPX file output.gpx

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr

When i try to export an shapefile to gpx using ogr2ogr.

```
ogr2ogr -f GPX output.gpx D:\mypaste\input.shp -sql "SELECT Id AS name FROM layername"
```

It gives me the following error "Failed to create GPX file output.gpx." "GPX driver failed to create output.gpx." Does anyone knows why this happens? How can i rectify this?

Comment: I thought that I would quickly solve the question for you, but I ended up confirming the same error message.  I didn't have any time to dig further.

Answer (score 2):

For GDAL/OGR a shapefile "input.shp" contains one layer and its name is "input". The right syntax is

```
ogr2ogr -f GPX output.gpx D:\mypaste\input.shp -sql "SELECT Id AS name FROM input"
```